# Using a Blade directive in a Blade directive

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel 5.1. I am trying to use a Blade directive (`@extend`) with my custom Blade directive.

```
Blade::directive('base', function() use ($theme) {
  return "@extends($theme)"
});
```

However, the above code only literally displays the contents (`@extends($theme)`)

Comment: Have you tried `return "@extends(".$theme.")";`

Comment: Doesn't work. It just outputs the entire thing

Comment: Unfortunately blade templates do not do second parses over the compiled view. This makes what you are doing very tough to accomplish without manually invoking the blade compiler to run a second parse.

Comment: @DavidBarker Yep, that's the answer to this.

Comment: @Ben not so sure anymore, it looks like it should be easily possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contrary to a comment I made earlier, I think this is possible (but untested) using the blade compiler.

```
Blade::directive('base', function() use ($theme) {
    return Blade::compileString("@extends({$theme})");
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for the @yield directive. Has anyone gotten this to work?

Comment: As in you're attempting to compile the yield in a directive?

Comment: I know this is an old thread but I just started using your solution in my project and the funny is that it is working - but only when my custom directive is used within a view that is called through a the native @include directive, but if I try to use my custom directive directly in the view i get WSOD... any insight into why that might be?

Comment: Oh interesting, I remember this working in Laravel 5.1 (I started to use this a lot a while back). I haven't tried it in Laravel 5.3+. I can't see why it wouldn't work, did you check the logs?

Comment: I tested in Laravel 5.8, remove the `return` ..just use this `Blade::compileString()` ....because if you use `return`, it will execute twice.