# How to use custom blade directive in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am trying to use the argument passed in the directive to evaluate a condition and returned a string like this

```
Blade::directive('resource', function($page) {
    return (strcmp(URL::full(), URL::to("/admin/" + $page)) == 0) ? "active" : "inactive";
});
```

If the page name passed in evaluates to the full url then return the active string, otherwise return inactive. For styling purposes

The problem is that $page evaluates to (value) where value is the string passed in. Am I able to use this argument to do calculation on conditions here?

The closest post I could find is [Using a Blade directive in a Blade directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30968498/using-a-blade-directive-in-a-blade-directive) but no answer.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Blade::directive('resource', function($page) {
    return "<?php echo '".((strcmp(URL::full(), URL::to("/admin/" + $page)) == 0) ? "active" : "inactive")."' ?>"
});
```

Comment: Where would be a good place to place those custom directives? thinking in good practice

Comment: AppServiceProvider file. Put your directives in boot() method.